# Meaning of “verstärkt” as an adverb

Tags: meaning-in-context

In my German book (B1), I encountered the following sentence:

> Ab Mitternacht denken die Programmgestalter verstärkt an einsame Herzen.

Normalerweise I would translate *verstärken* with *to enforce,* but this does not seem to work in this sentence. Additionally, I do not really understand the preposition *ab* in this context. I tried looking it up, but my dictionary does not help my much.

Comment: Please note: "verstärkt" is an adverb here, so it refers to the verb "denken". So your "enforced" becomes "in an enforced way". Perhaps that puts you on the right track? (Just an additional thought complementing to the good answers below.)

Comment: @Stephie Yes I think my problem was indeed that I did not recognize that it was an adverb. I thought it was a verb. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context *verstaerkt* means that they think *more* about the lonley hearts. An the *ab* means that *from* midnight *on*.

Generally I would say that doing something *verstaerkt* means doing it *more intensively*

Answer (score 3):

*Verstärken* can also mean to *increase, reinforce, strengthen*. In this case it simply means that from midnight on (ab Mitternacht) lonely hearts (einsame Herzen) are a particular concern of theirs, that they focus on them, gear their program towards them.